# How do i pre-process the http request before creating the controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In WebAPI, when I wanted to do some work with the http request before the controller was called, all I did was create a DelegatingHandler and did my pre and post controller operations in there, then register in the WebApiConfig. It would appear that this is not the same with internet applications.

I'm having a hard time finding where to intercept the request, where can I do this?

Comment: How about an [`ActionFilter`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) and `OnActionExecuting`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That lead me down correct path. But is this executing after the controller is created? I noticed that my Session object is null when I try to get at it in the controller OnActionExecuting

Comment: are you referring to `filterContext.HttpContext.Session`?

Comment: No, I overrode it in the controller itself. I think I'm alright though. I just noticed that there's a controller reference in the filter where I can stuff it into the ViewBag. If you enter your suggestion as an answer, I will select it so you can get some credit :)